# laravel unique() dont work with paginating

Tags: laravel, group-by, pagination, unique, distinct

i'm facing with an issue in laravel 5.7.28, i'm trying to get records with all of my fields and paginate them , sadly i got a bug in my code that cause registering users with duplicate phone number(a user registered itself more than one time and of course i fix the bug ) , for now i'm facing with a scenario that i want to fetch my (non-duplicate) distinct users on their phone, and paginate them . here is wishful scenario :

```
$users = User::distinct('phone')
->doesntHave('carrierUsers')
->doesntHave('thirdparty')
->latest()->paginate(40);
```

it returns all users (with duplicate phone number), seems distinct function not affected , so i tried unique function :

```
$users = User::doesntHave('carrierUsers')
->doesntHave('thirdparty')
->latest()->paginate(40)->unique('phone');
```

it works (for getting non-duplicate) but break paginating functionality

and for

```
$users = User::doesntHave('carrierUsers')
->doesntHave('thirdparty')
->latest()
->unique('phone')
->paginate(40);
```

i got error for undefined function on builder , means it works on collections , 
also i tried groupBy (search whole the web for solution) , it makes me confused till when i use it

```
User::doesntHave('carrierUsers')->doesntHave('thirdparty')
->latest()->groupBy('phone')
->paginate(40);
```

i got `SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause`, is that mean in every phrase in my select statement (for now is all ('*') ) i should use it in my groupBy ?
i mean i need all columns , how can i have all those column in groupBy clause ? whats that mean by the way ?

, error is telling : *this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by*. is she making this happen ? how can i fix it ?
1) excuse me for my english 
2) Thanks for reading whole this 
3) pleasure to reply and help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem 1: Use distinct

For `distinct()` method, passing parameters is not supporteds, so `distinct(phone)` will not works.

You can use `->select('phone')->distinct()` instead. However,  support unique column is selected.

### Problem 2: Use Group By

So if you want to **select all columns and unique one column**, you can use `group by`.

And because you are using mysql 5.7+.

> The ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY and STRICT_TRANS_TABLES modes were added in MySQL 5.7.5.

So if you select all columns and group one column, you will get the `only_full_group_by` error.

There are two options can solve this problem.

#### Solution1:

Use `ANY_VALUE()`

```php
User::doesntHave('carrierUsers')->doesntHave('thirdparty')
->latest()
->selectRaw('phone, ANY_VALUE(id) AS id, ANY_VALUE(username) AS username, ...')
->groupBy('phone')
->paginate(40);
```

#### Solution2:

In config/database.php configuration, set strict mode to `false`(This is not very safty):

```php
'mysql' => [
   'driver' => 'mysql',
   ...
   'strict' => false,
],
```

Comment: Thanks , solution one (your recommended one) did the job .

Comment: @alireza u'r welcome, plz give me a upvote or accepted the answer.